# jQuery template renders hidden form field as a visible input box in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery templates to add new items to a list when a button is pressed

The template contains a hidden field.

When I add a new item to the list in IE 8 or IE 9, then the hidden form field is displayed like a visible input field

I've set up a JSfiddle to demonstrate
http://jsfiddle.net/T3has/8/

It works fine in Chrome and FF, but not IE

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it right; the input is of type "hidden", so this is clearly (yet another) bug in IE.
If you **want** to support IE you may want to try adding a class to those inputs as a hack around this:

```
<input class="hidden-input" ...
```

and css

```
input.hidden-input: {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add .hide() to the line where you append.

The function .tmpl() is marked as a beta feature in jQuery, and is not being further developed.

"The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta. It is no longer being actively developed or maintained."
Source: http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/

Try using this code instead:

```
$('#rateItemTemplate').clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('#Board');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T3has/10/

Comment: Indeed; tmpl looks promising, but I've stayed clear of it since it seems to have died in beta.

Comment: yes - I would avoid but it's the templating library already in use on this project

Comment: tried your updated fiddle - it doesn't do anything. Nothing added to the DOM. Also, why would you want to remove the ID?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.
The entire element cloned and then hidden. Not only the input itself. :)